# override justify-content and center a flex box item horizontally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

THIS post offers an excellent solution as of how to override the value of `justify-content` since there is no `justify-self`available, however the problem I am facing a notch higher in magnitude. I don't want to just override the value of `justify-content` , but place an item at exactly the center of the wrapper horizontally. Let's get to the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bx"></div>
  <div class="bx move-it"></div>
  <div class="bx"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bx {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.wrapper > div:first-child {
  width: 300px;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(2) {
    background: pink;
 }

/*.move-it {
    background: pink;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}*/
```

I have commented the last line of code deliberately, two thing to notice here, I want the pink div in the middle to be horizontally center, notice how since the first div is much bigger in width it (pink div) does't get aligned in the `center`. (P.S. its flexbox's `space-between` at work here.). So well how do i align the pink div in the middle ?

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/4e5znk39/1/)**

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate because the [top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) contains a complete answer (see BOX #71) to your question. If you feel this is not a dupe post a comment.

Comment: @Michael_B ohh .. its u again ! haha Thanks . let me go through that answer tomorrow.